# How to move to View Controller from GameScene in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a view controller as my initial controller and a game scene. My game includes collision detection, and when it is detected, it needs to launch the view controller.

Inside the function that lauches when the collision is detected is this:

```
func Collision(Circle: SKSpriteNode, Triangle: SKSpriteNode) {
        var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("1") as! UIViewController
        self.view!.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
2015-07-04 18:53:52.491 doj[5130:264706] Warning: Attempt to present <doj.ViewControllerStart: 0x14e13630> on <doj.ViewControllerStart: 0x14eef560> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

(doj is the name of the application)

How can I get to my view controller form the game scene without giving this error?

Comment: You need to present that view controller from the top-most view controller.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here is that the gigantic optional chain on the third line is giving you something that is unexpect. You'd probably it to return the view controller that has the SKView in it (GameViewController.swift in most projects), but it seems like it's doing something wierd. Instead of trying to debug this, I would recommend creating a delegate, which will allow you to call `presentViewController()` from the UIViewController class that is included in your project. This will take away the call to the rootViewController property of UIView, which is probably where the error is.

This has a few parts:

In your scene file (e.g. GameScene.Swift), add a protocol with a method that the SKScene will sent to the SKViewController

```
protocol GameSceneDelegate {

    func launchViewController(#scene: SKScene)
}
```

Now, add the following property to the SKScene

```
var collisionDelegate: GameSceneDelegate?
```

Now, in the collision function, you just call the delegate:

```
func Collision(Circle: SKSpriteNode, Triangle: SKSpriteNode) {
    self.collisionDelegate.launchViewController(scene: self)
}
```

In your View Controller file (e.g. GameViewController.swift) you need to implement this protocol - declare it and implement the method

```
 class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameSceneDelegate {


    func launchViewController(scene: SKScene) {
        var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("1") as! UIViewController
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // note that you don't need to go through a bunch of optionals to call presentViewController
    }

    // .... OTHER CODE ....
}
```

And last, but not least, you need to put the following line of code BEFORE you call `skView.presentScene(scene)`

```
scene.collisionDelegate = self
```

Sorry for the complexity, but this delegate should fix your problem, or if it doesn't it will become clear where the problem is.